# WPF: Cant find correct BorderBrush after setting Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, styles

I have a button which I apply a style too. After the style is applied I have a test that checks the BorderBrush of the button to make sure the style was correctly applied. This test always fails, because the BorderBrush never gets updated in the Buttons properties.

Is there a way for me to get the actual BorderBrush being displayed? All i can get is the default BorderBrush, not the applied styles value.

The style I am using is this:

```
    <Style  x:Key="ActiveModuleBtnStyleOn" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Margin="0" 
                                    BorderThickness="3" 
                                    BorderBrush="Green" 
                                    Background="White" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                    CornerRadius="4" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="Black" Direction="325" Opacity=".5" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="5" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
</Style>
```

Then I apply the style like this:

```
if(var1 == 1)
  TopologyNvTxBtn.Style = this.FindResource("ActiveModuleBtnStyleOn") as Style;
else
  TopologyNvTxBtn.Style = this.FindResource("ActiveModuleBtnStyleOff") as Style;
```

In my test app, I want to check which style has been applied. The difference between the two styles is the border brush. I would like to do something like this:

```
if(TopologyNvTxBtn.BorderBrush == Brushes.Green)
  return PASS;
```

But the BorderBrush never changes (e.g. in a watch window, it stays the same as the default buttons style BorderBrush), but its definitely applied correctly as in the GUI it turns green.

How can i access this property in my test?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Andy, the `Border`is set inside the `ControlTemplate`of the Button. Check this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) for more information!

Comment: Does that mean i cant access it at run time?

Comment: You'll have to set your own `Template` - refer below.

Comment: Dont forget to add `x:Name` for your elements!

Comment: A great tool to inspect elements and their respective style is [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

A MUST HAVE if you plan to develop in WPF and style your own elements and controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BorderBrush property of the Button is not bound to anything in your template. You need to do this in the control template:

```
<Style  x:Key="ActiveModuleBtnStyleOn" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Border Margin="0" 
                                BorderThickness="3" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                Background="White" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                CornerRadius="4" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="Black" Direction="325" Opacity=".5" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="5" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
</Style>
```

Notice how the BorderBrush is now bound to the BorderBrush property of the Button. Then you you can set the BorderBrush in the style and should be able to access it in this way:

```
if(TopologyNvTxBtn.BorderBrush == Brushes.Green)
```

Let me know if that works.

Cheers,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

As I stated above, the `Border` is part of the `Button` `ControlTemplate`. I just launched Blend and got a copy of the "Factory" template. With this, you can do pretty much everything with it (assuming you know about Stylying.):

```
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

MSDN has a good introductory tutorial about `Style` and `Templates`. Besides, you can find tons of articles around the web!

The `Button` itself is pretty much this:

```
<Border
         x:Name="border"
         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
         BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
         BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
         SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
         <ContentPresenter
            x:Name="contentPresenter"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
            Focusable="False"
            RecognizesAccessKey="True"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
</Border>
```

So, what your looking for is `Triggers`, you'll have to add and change as you wish these tags:

```
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Things to pay attention: `TargetName` and every `<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">` alike!
Good luck!

Comment: Thats great, but thats what i have already. there is no problem setting the style i want, thats all good. the problem is finding what style was set after its set. I have a button style with a green border, but I cant see it anywhere. If i look at the button object the border is still grey. if i look at the screen its green.

Comment: The `Trigger` tags take care of what happen to which property when some action, like `MouseOver`, happens. You can either put your style between `<Button.Resources>` tags or set them somewhere else and reference the `xaml` in your files.

Comment: I cant see how that tells me what style I am using, which is the information I need. Am I missing something? I need a way to access the Border at run time after the style is applies, see my edit to the original post.

Comment: Now I'm not sure whay you mean..anyway. You have to give your elements a `x:Name` in order to access and cast them.